# Should I disable "Delayed Launcher" in my startup programs?

Tags: boot, intel-rst

What exactly does this program do? I know it's there because my PC has Intel Rapid Storage Technology which makes storage faster, but why does it need to add a "Delayed Launcher" program at startup.

What could be the consequences if I disable this program?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently asked Intel support about this process, and the short answer is, yes you can disable and even uninstall Rapid Storage Technology from your computer.

quotes from Intel support:

> About the question if Intel® has a website explaining what is the
> Intel delayed launcher, no we do not have it but I can do a research
> with our Intel® Specialist on this topic to get some information for you

..

> by removing the Intel® Rapid Storage the Intel Delayed Launcher is also
> uninstalled. Also, since you do not have any RAID installed as you mentioned,
> you can uninstall it if you do not need it.

And for reference, Intel rapid storage page:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology.html

Tested SSD speed with [CrystalMark](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/crystaldiskmark/9nblggh4z6f2?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) (and didn't notice any difference)

1. With Rapid Storage installed and Delayed Launcher running

[image: with rapid]

2. With Rapid Storage and Delayed Launcher uninstalled (and reboot)

[image: no rapid]

***Update 2020:**
Saw this piece of information in ASRock website:

> Intel Rapid Storage Technology provides benefits to users of a single
> drive as well. Through AHCI, storage performance is improved through
> Native Command Queuing(NCQ). AHCI also delivers longer battery life
> with Link Power Management (LPM), which can reduce the power
> consumption of the chipset and Serial ATA (SATA) hard drive.
> https://download.asrock.com/Manual/RAID/Z390%20Taichi/IntelRapidStorage/English.pdf

Answer (score 3):

> "Should I disable.."

Just disable it.

Since you wont be asking if you are not poking around with the startup options..

> "What could be the consequences if I disable this program?"

Just FYI, in my case it doesn't move a thing.. I didn't notice any significant performance improvement either. I don't know if that's the case for others.

> "why does it need to add a "Delayed Launcher" program at startup. "

On this part I really don't know why Intel do it.. IMHO, If it is up to me.. I would do the same to my startup sequence.. I DO want my windows component to properly loads first.. then only other background application.. except for antivirus, where I think the earlier the better.

Hope this helps in any ways possible. ( :

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, it seems delayed launcher or IAStorIconLaunch.exe from Intel RST uses the local run registry setting to execute when a user logs in Windows. Doing that actually delays your boot time for about 30-60 seconds before viruses or malware can interfere with system files. This also allows Intel RRT to restore the hard disk from the "recovery partition" which is maintained using RAID 1 mirroring and runned in the background. It's basically a system recovery measure but also allows your Windows system to load before any other apps like viruses/malware. This service can be disabled via "msconfig" through the Run application or through the task manager's Startup tab

[source](https://appuals.com/how-to-disable-intel-delayed-launcher/)